# Cannot run pwmconfig (There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed)

Tags: graphics, laptop, amd-graphics, amd, fan

I’m trying to control the fan speed in my laptop (Huawei Matebook D14 2020. AMD Ryzen 5 3500U with Vega GPU). I’ve installed lm_sensors, and run sudo sensors-detect. However, when I try to run sudo pwmconfig, I get this output:

```
# pwmconfig version 3.6.0
This program will search your sensors for pulse width modulation (pwm)
controls, and test each one to see if it controls a fan on
your motherboard. Note that many motherboards do not have pwm
circuitry installed, even if your sensor chip supports pwm.

We will attempt to briefly stop each fan using the pwm controls.
The program will attempt to restore each fan to full speed
after testing. However, it is ** very important ** that you
physically verify that the fans have been to full speed
after the program has completed.

/usr/bin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed
```

What can I do?

sensors-detect output (last lines):

```
Now follows a summary of the probes I have just done.
Just press ENTER to continue: 
Driver `k10temp' (autoloaded):
  * Chip `AMD Family 17h thermal sensors' (confidence: 9)

No modules to load, skipping modules configuration.

Unloading i2c-dev... OK
```

Comment: What did `sensors-detect` say? If it found anything, it would produce a list of modules to load, which has to be done before `pwmconfig` can work. If it didn’t, there’s nothing much to be done unless you’d like to help add support for your hardware to the kernel.

Comment: @StephenKitt thanks for answer, I updated the thread...

Comment: @StephenKitt is it possible that my fans can't be controlled by software but only by hardware?

Comment: that would be surprising; it’s far more likely that your fan controller isn’t (yet) supported by the kernel.